# Why can't I get $(f)'*g = f*(g)'$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to show that the above equality holds when $f(t)=e^{at}$ and $g(t)=e^{bt}$. However, I get different values. So, I get that $f'(t) = ae^{at}$ and $g'(t)=be^{bt}$.

$$
(f')*g = \int_0^t f'(t-u)g(u) du \\
= \int_0^t ae^{a(t-u)}e^{bu} du \\
= a\int_0^t e^{at}e^{bu-au} du \\
= ae^{at} \int_0^t e^{u(b-a)} \\
= ae^{at} (\big(\frac{1}{b-a}\big)e^{bt}-e^{at}) \\
$$

Through a similar fashion I get $be^{bt}(\big(\frac{1}{a-b}e^{at}-e^{bt})$ for $f*g'$. Now, these two are unequal and I am not sure where I made a mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your functions don't have compact support, i.e. the boundary integrals when doing integration by parts don't vanish.

Comment: Are you sure about your integration ? I would say $ae^{at} \int_0^t e^{u(b-a)} = ae^{at} \frac{1}{b-a}(e^{t(b-a)} - 1) = \frac{a}{b-a}(e^{tb} - e^{ta})$

Answer (score 1):

There's a small typo at your final equality, but even if you fix it the two integrals will be different.

The equality $f'*g = f*g'$ holds for convolutions where the integral is taken from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

You seem to be computing "causal convolutions", i.e. looking at the function $f$ where $f(t) = e^{at}$ for $t > 0$ and $f(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$ and similarly for $g$. In that case you need to take distributional derivatives (or something equivalent to that) for the formula $f'*g = f*g'$ to be correct.